# Using live data from Blaze DS in a swf file

Tags: c++, apache-flex, adobe, flash, blazeds

I currently have a c++ client which can play SWF, AVI, BIK etc
It uses DirectX9 to render the graphics

I currently have a requirement for dynamic SWF files, which would retrieve data from a BlazeDS server and put certain text in certain places depending on the retrieved data

From what I have read, BlazeDS talks to Adobe Flex and Adobe AIR applications

Would that mean I would have to convert my current c++ client into a Flex application

Sorry if this seems like a stupid question, I'm just having trouble trying to figure out how Blaze and Flex and Air all fit together

Answer (score 2):

It's a litte unclear what you're asking, so let me have a crack:

Assuming that you have a c++ runtime that you want to communicate with BlazeDS, you could write a c++ implementation of the [AMF protocol](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/Developer+Documentation).

The protocol itself is open source, and there may even be c++ implementations of it out there already.

I assume from your question that the client that is rendering the SWF is not the flash player.  If this is the case, switching your c++ app to Flex won't win you anything, as Flex itself doesn't know how to handle AMF -- the serialization process is handled by the flash player, rather than the flex framework.

Comment: My c++ application uses the IShockwaveFlash interface. So basically creates a swf container and copies its content into a surface on update
I was given a swf file that communicates with the Blaze DS server, I ran the swf the same as I would a static SWf and it worked fine
So basically flash player is doing all the work and I'm just copying the result into my surface